# Adding moment to Laravel via webpack

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, momentjs

So I know that moment JS library has a known issue with trying to require ./locale. All I know is that the issue is still not fixed and you are supposed to find some solution from several tickets and leave it at that. I would be happy to include any workaround, however I am completely new to npm, webpack, whatever. I have 0 idea how to implement any of those lines in Laravel webpack.

The issue mentioned here: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2979

I am trying to include it in a file called app.js along with other main libraries (e.g. I am including jquery, jquery ui, semantic ui etc). I did seem to run npm without errors with "require('moment').default;" but moment was undefined on the page.

Can anyone perhaps help me out and educate me?

Comment: Show us your webpack configuration and the file that is attempting to use moment.

Comment: It's pretty stock Laravel. This is very similar to my JS: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js ... I am just trying to "require" moment. And this is Laravel webpack: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have managed to resolve the issue.

It turns out that in Node.js they do not automatically export moment, which is why with require('moment').default it was undefined.

Additionally we ended up with

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
```

which threw no errors.

Answer (score 3):

I used Laravel with our vue, and initially used as below

```
require('moment');
```

It didn't work me at all then used as follows, its done then.

```
window.moment = require('moment/moment');
```